# props.onAddNewExpense is not a function . wrong in js.react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

hi guys i am trying to send the data from NewComponent component  to App component in react while i am trying to do this it gives me an error and i tried hrad to solve this problem but i coudn't

here as you see this is the component that i will take the information form it and i will send it to newcomponent component exactly i will send expenseData object's information up (from child to parent ) but when i do this it gives me this error (props.onAddNewExpense is not a function)

this is the expense form component

```
import React , {useState} from "react";
import "./ExpenseForm.css"

const ExpenseForm = (props) => {
    
    //the setEnteredTitle  will be like a function i can do a refreshing with it .

    const [enteredTitle,setEnteredTitle]=useState("")
    const [enteredAmount,setEnteredAmount]=useState("")
    const [enteredDate,setEnteredDate]=useState("")

 


    const TitleChangeHandeler=(eo) => {
        setEnteredTitle(eo.target.value)
        console.log(setEnteredTitle)


       
    }

    const amountChangeHnadeler= (eo) => {
        
        
        setEnteredAmount(eo.target.value)

       
    }

    const DateChangeHnadeler= (eo) => {
        setEnteredDate(eo.target.value)
    }


    const submitHandeler=(eo) => {

     eo.preventDefault(); // it make me to prevent the dafoult that make the page refresh
    
      const expenseData={
        Title:enteredTitle,
        Amount:enteredAmount,
        Date:new Date(enteredDate)
        
      }
      
      console.log(expenseData)
      props.onSaveExpenseData(expenseData)
      //when the user make a submit it will give a empty data for the sates 
      setEnteredTitle("");
      setEnteredAmount("");
      setEnteredDate("");

      
    }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitHandeler}>
      <div className="new-expense__controls">
        <div className="new-expense__control">
          <label>Title</label>
          <input type="text" className="input"  onChange={TitleChangeHandeler} value={enteredTitle} />
        </div>

        <div className="new-expense__control">
          <label> Amount </label>
          <input type="number" step="0.01" min="0.01"  className="input" onChange={amountChangeHnadeler} value={enteredAmount}/>
        </div>

        <div className="new-expense__control">
          <label>DATE</label>
          <input type="date" min="3-12-2021" max="01-01-2025"  onChange={DateChangeHnadeler} value={enteredDate} />
        </div>

        <div className="new-expense__actions">
          <button type="submit"> Add expense </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default ExpenseForm;
```

and this is the parent component

```
import React  from 'react'
import "./NewComponent.css"
import ExpenseForm from "./ExpenseForm"

const NewComponent = (props) => {
   

    const saveExpenseDataHandeler= (enteredExpenseData) => {
        
        const expenseData = {
            
            ...enteredExpenseData ,
            id:Math.random().toString()

        }
        props.onAddNewExpense(expenseData)
       

        } 

        //here we just point to the function we did not execute it here 
     return (
        <div className="new-expense">
        <ExpenseForm  onSaveExpenseData={saveExpenseDataHandeler} />
        </div>
         )
}

export default NewComponent
```

we can see that i fetch the component props and i am trying to take the child data from there

thanks alot for any answer will come

Comment: where you declare onAddNewExpense function??Where does parent props come from?

Comment: it is come from the app component as a data in an array